# Integrate Bootstrap-like framework into Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use [PlusStrap framework](http://xbreaker.github.com/plusstrap/) into my Rails application. As I see it is a Bootstrap which was slightly customized.

I have included css-file in my layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "plusstrap.min.css" %>
```

But when I look at this CSS file I have found such image refs:

```
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

I have created assets/img folder and put image file into it, but Rails cannot find this images.  How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to include anything , refferenced by CSS's url call is :

```
background-image: url("/images/yourpic.png")
```

The Rails framework handles it in a special way....

Comment: If I understand you correctly you offer to change CSS files? I want to avoid it :)

Comment: It's pity , but you'll have to . That's why there are gems , derived by frameworks . Right now I have no idea how to avoid it .

Comment: You can also try to include your css by declaring it in application.css . I think by including it there instead of calling it by stylesheet_link_tag it's gonna handle the path correctly . (Don't forget to add .scss )

Comment: I think routes.rb manages MVC functionality , .css files are static assets . They are precompiled (in most cases in Rails ) and served differently than the dynamic content , generated by models , views and controllers . Here is a [good article](http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/) how to integrate (in general) twitter-bootstrap .

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder structure, is it really pointing to the image?. Check the documentation for relative paths in rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the css file, you could put it in a folder like `app/assets/stylesheets/plusstrap/plusstrap.min.css` and the images in `app/assets/images/img/` so you'll call the css with:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "plusstrap/plusstrap.min.css" %>
```

I know, it could be redundant, but is an effective way if you want to keep your css as the original.